# Why check for len(s) >= 0? Doesn't it always return true?

Tags: python

When does len(s) return a negative value? Isn't it always >= 0? I've found this condition in multiple open source Python projects. For example, this code snippet is from Keras:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/32b15912a216a5517e751c810e3f172c3b8f6be2/keras/engine/training_distributed_v1.py#L463

```py
if len(outs) >= 0:
   outs[0] /= target_steps
```

The statement inside if will always be executed. So what is the logic behind the if condition here?

Comment: It's valid for a collection to be empty, e.g. a list with no elements: `len([]) == 0`

Comment: @hhimko 0 is still `>= 0`

Comment: @hhimko
So 0 is still >=0. My question is if len(s) is always >= 0, then what is the logic to add this condition. It will be always true.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Seems like a bug to me, because the code definitely tries to guard against throwing `IndexError` at `outs[0]`. Python doesn't even allow a custom class to return anything < 0 from `__len__`.

Comment: It's probably supposed to be `>`.

Comment: This was in fact a bug. It got [fixed](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/70e550307a6de96e276086164e365e8120093154) two weeks after this question was asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two pieces of code produce the same results:

#### EXAMPLE ONE

```python
if len(outs) >= 0:
    print("BLAH")
```

#### EXAMPLE TWO

```python
print("BLAH")
```

There is no point in checking if the length of an object is a negative value. `len(outs) >= 0`